# Rのパッケージのロードが失敗する

Tags: r, dplyr

R3.3.2をWin8.1でRstudio1.0で使っています。
tidyverseを用いようとすると

```
> library(tidyverse)
Loading tidyverse: ggplot2
Loading tidyverse: tibble
Loading tidyverse: tidyr
Loading tidyverse: readr
Loading tidyverse: purrr
Loading tidyverse: dplyr
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/user/Documents/R/R-3.3.2/library/scales/R/scales.rdb': No such file or directory
Error :  .onAttach は attachNamespace()（'tidyverse' に対する）の中で失敗しました、詳細は: 
  call: NULL 
  error:  ‘ggplot2’ に対するパッケージもしくは名前空間のロードが失敗しました  
Error:  ‘tidyverse’ に対するパッケージもしくは名前空間のロードが失敗しました
```

となってしまいます。最初はうまく読み込めていたのでDLし直したりしたのですがうまくいかないので`dplyr`などバラバラに読み込まざるを得ない状況です。
対処法をご存じの方よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

おそらく,以下の内容が今回の問題に近いと思います:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717850/error-package-or-namespace-load-failed-for-ggplot2-and-for-data-table

エラーメッセージを読んだ限りでは,`scales`パッケージの名前空間がうまく読み込めていないようですので,`scales`パッケージの最新版を再インストールしてみて,その後に`ggplot2`パッケージを再インストールしてみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: scalesとggplot2を再インストールしたら今度はtidyr、それも再インストールしたらpurrrについてエラーが出たためまた再インストールしたら無事読み込まれるようになりました。ありがとうございました。